# Object Classes not working with RLMSupport in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

Hello When using Realm and RLMSupport for Obj-C/Swift.

The app crashes with my conf when adding `config.objectClasses`

```
let appGroupIdentifier = "group.APContacts"
let dbFilename = "dbSwiftContacts.realm"

let config = RLMRealmConfiguration()
config.fileURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroupIdentifier)!.appendingPathComponent(dbFilename)
config.objectClasses = [Dog.className()]
config.readOnly = true
RLMRealmConfiguration.setDefault(config)
```

The error is:
[This one!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1UYH.png)

Can anyone managed to get this working with RLMSupport?

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger and check what is the actual error and which line is causing it.

Comment: Please post the complete backtrace of the crash you're seeing rather than a screenshot of a single stack frame. You can get the backtrace in textual form using `bt` in Xcode's LLDB console after you've crashed. Please also share the definition of the `Dog` class referenced in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and solved it.

Here is the correct field fixed: (using YourClass.self)

```
config.objectClasses = [YourClass.self]
```

Once there are no Doc for RLMSupport.swift , hope this will help someone.